# Is it possible to calculate how much Oxygen plants release indoors

Tags: houseplants

My room has two small Aloe Vera, one huge Peace Lily and tiny peace lily.

Is there way to calculate how much oxygen they're creating or are there any **consumer** devices to measure the levels in the air?

Comment: Usually, cheap devices measures CO2. Note: oxygen is dangerous in high levels (but you will never get so much from plants).

Comment: There are [oxy-meters](http://www.sysmatec.ch/eD6_O2_CO2_Measurement.html) available, but why would you want to measure O2? Just curious.

Comment: I'm more of the scientific kind - so it will literally to be so I can quantifiably see the difference when I introduce plants into my room :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about gardening.

Comment: I'd bet most rooms aren't air-tight enough to really notice more/less oxygen

Comment: great question,

Comment: @Xen2050 that's a great point - never really thought about that

Comment: I think this question belongs to Biology SE where you could receive better answers. Please consider this option.